# Create an array in object type

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to create an array in object type. But I couldn't make it ? How can I make it ?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE object AS OBJECT
 (
     type array1 IS VARRAY(1000) OF INTEGER,
     exAr1 array1,
     type array2 IS VARRAY(1000) OF INTEGER,   
     exAr2 array2,
 );
 /
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the other types as database objects too:

```
create type array1 is varray(1000) of integer;
/

create type array2 is varray(1000) of integer;   
/

create or replace type object as object
 (
     exar1 array1,
     exar2 array2
 );
```

Of course, since `array1` and `array2` types are identical, you don't really need them both:

```
create type array is varray(1000) of integer;
/

create or replace type object as object
 (
     exar1 array,
     exar2 array
 );
```

Comment: I already know this solution but I want to declare directly. Unfortunately we have just one solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @FatihCeng `but I want to declare directly` you can't. To be able to use `varray` as an ADT attribute's type, `varray` must be  defined at schema level.

Comment: I m new in plsql. I just know basic level programming rules. Thank you @Nicholas Krasnov for information

Answer (score 1):

```
Hey please try to create first TABLE TYPE and then reference it while creating the OBJECT Type. Let me know if this helps

--Table type creation first
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_NTT1
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_NTT
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;

--Object creation after that
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE object
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    exAr1 NUMBER_NTT,
    exAr2 NUMBER_NTT1 
);
```